The pause is not removed after switching from the pause menu to the main menu
I have a MainMenu node, which I go to after clicking on the corresponding button in the pause menu of the game. So, the pause remains and nothing works. And conditionally, I can't press the "Start" button in the main menu again. Its Godot 4.2.2
Perhaps this happens "Always", just like the
func _ready():
    process_mode = Node.PROCESS_MODE_ALWAYS

and
func _on_exit_menu_button_up():
    print("Exit the menu, cancel the pause in the game").
    Global.paused = false
    get_tree().paused = false`your text`
    print("The game is not paused, the scene is changing")
    get_tree().change_scene_to_packed(menu_scene)


I have found a solution to my problem. Perhaps someone will also encounter this.
Here is the section of code where the error occurred:
func _ready():
    
    process_mode = Node.PROCESS_MODE_ALWAYS
    time_label.position = Vector2(10, 10) # Отступы от краёв экрана
    day_label.position = Vector2(10, 65)


var menu_scene = load("res://Scenes/MainMenu/MainMenu.tscn")

func _on_exit_menu_button_up():
    get_tree().paused = false
    get_tree().change_scene_to_packed(menu_scene)

The problem was that initially I had preload instead of load. I decided to change it and everything was fixed.
